# Aggregates that require sharing of an entity

Tags: language-agnostic, domain-driven-design, entity, aggregate, aggregateroot

Consider my scenario of a model consisting of two aggregate roots, `Customer` and `Order` as well as a "shared" entity `Address`.

Also note that `Address` is `abstract` has the following subclasses: `PhysicalAddress`, `PostOfficeBoxAddress` and `PrivateBagAddress`.

A `Customer` can have many addresses organized into some sort of address book.
Upon making an order a customer would select an `Address` from their address book to be used as a delivery address.

My initial thoughts were to share an address between the two entities, but I have since opted out as it will cause trouble with managing the respective invariants.

Another option I could go for is to create two hierarchies of `Address`, each for their purposes as a customer address or delivery address. This again doesn't seem right as there is a lot of repeated code.

How would I model this situation properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An entity is something that should be able to exist by ifself such as a customer or order. However an Address is not an entity, an Address is a value type and cannot exist on its own hence:

1. An Address can only exist as a value type that is aggregated within an entity
2. You can define your address hierarchy as a value type in your domain but many entities may use this.

We find that we come across these types of entities all the time such as Address, MoneyType etc.

Solution would be to create 1 Address hierarchy value type in your domain. Then any entity can have an Address as a property where applicable

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however it appears that I cannot implement this with my ORM framework, JPA. Problem being that @Embeddables (value objects) aren't able to make use of inheritance. I'll have to look for another solution.